# Why an auto scheduled app from Java didn't start on Windows?

Tags: java, jvm, monitoring, sleep

I have a Java Swing app that is supposed to start a 2nd JVM, my code looks like this :

```
public class App_A implements Runnable
{
  ...
  public static void start2ndJVM() throws Exception
  {
    String separator=System.getProperty("file.separator"),classpath=System.getProperty("java.class.path"),path=System.getProperty("java.home")+separator+"bin"+separator+"java";

    pb=new ProcessBuilder(path,"-cp",classpath,App_B.class.getName(),"Auto Exit !");
    pb.directory(new File("Dir_Data"));
    File log=new File("Log.txt");
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(log));
  }

  public void run()
  {
    try
    {
      Timer.Start();
      while (true)
      {
        Thread.sleep(60*1000);                                                                                         // Sleep for 1 minute                         
        if (Timer.getTimeFormat(-1,2).equals("23:00")) start2ndJVM();                             // 18:28  Run every night at 11 PM to update stock data
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
  }
...
}
```

There is no problem with Timer.getTimeFormat, I've tested it many times when I'm looking at the screen, App_A starts, when it comes to the time I specify, it will start the 2nd JVM and the App_B starts as I would like to see, but the problem is when I set it to run at 11 pm, while I was not in front of the screen, it won't run, I think it's the windows' sleep function that is causing the problem, my monitor goes to sleep if there is no action for 15 minutes, the screen goes dark, but I set my PC not to go to sleep, so I wonder could it be the inactivation of monitor caused my app not to run on time ? Because when I came back in the morning and moved the mouse a bit, the monitor will wake up, and I can see my App_A is still running on screen, it just did start the App_B on 11 pm, why ?

I forgot to mention, I jarred the App_A and App_B into a jar file and put that jar file in the Windows 7's Startup dir, and restarted the PC, after the PC restarts, my App_A immediately starts to run, but after the monitor goes to sleep, App_A failed to auto start App_B at 11 pm on time.

Comment: Note: instead of `Thread.sleep(60 * 1000)`, you can use `TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1L)`

Comment: Probably not your problem, but if you sleep for one minute and rely on the timer activating during exactly that one minute, you could miss it. The sleep isn't exact, and it's possible to sleep for 61 seconds and completely miss your intended minute. That's not likely your problem, but worth keeping in mind. You may wish to sleep for 45 seconds instead, something like that, or, better yet, figure out how long until you want to wake up, then just issue one sleep until then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, found the problem, I need to also copy the lib dir that contains a needed jar file into the Startup dir to make it run correctly.