# Why this in Java will cause the 2nd JVM not to start in the startup app?

Tags: java, variable-assignment, startup

I'm writing a Java `App_A` that can auto start `App_B` when windows starts, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108997/why-an-auto-scheduled-app-from-java-didnt-start-on-windows). 
But I found `App_A` can auto start `App_B` only in the NetBeans environment, after I jarred it and put the jar file in the windows' Startup dir, it won't work, I looked carefully at it and found out why it didn't work.

When there is something like this, it won't work :

```
public class App_B extends JPanel implements Runnable
{
  String Text="text";
  static String labelText="Label A";
...
}
```

It only works when I changed the above code to the following :

```
public class App_B extends JPanel implements Runnable
{
  String Text;
  static String labelText;
...

  void Init()
  {
    Text="text";
    labelText="Label A";
  }
}
```

I do need something like :

```
public class My_Lib
{
  static String myText="Constant";
...
}
```

So in my `App_A` or `App_B`, I can call `My_Lib.myText`, but this causes the app not to work in the Startup. Why ? What's the solution ?

Comment: Don't you need a command to launch the jar? `java -jar App_A.jar` Just put this in a bat-file. This might launch the app in the correct Java environment

Comment: Make myLib as interface and implement it.

Comment: I tried to put it in a bat-file, it did save me one step so I don't have to restart windows to test it, but when it failed to work from windows startup dir, it also failed from the bat-file, when it works from startup dir, it also worked from the bar-file.